# SQL sort string with numbers certain pattern first

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by, case

I have a table that has a column (cat_name). Some are strings followed by numbers and others are just plain strings. I like to arrange it by putting all strings starting with 'Level' first.

**Desired output:**

- Level 1 Items
- Level 2 Items
- Level 3 Items
- Level 5 Items
- Level 10 Items
- Level 12 Items
- Level 22 Items
- Apple
- Mango
- Others
- Special Items

I used this query

```
SELECT * FROM category ORDER BY
(CASE WHEN cat_name LIKE 'Level%' THEN 0
ELSE 1
END) ASC, cat_name
```

And got

- Level 1 Items
- Level 10 Items
- Level 12 Items
- Level 2 Items
- Level 22 Items
- Level 3 Items
- Level 5 Items
- Apple
- Mango
- Others
- Special Items

And found this query here at stackoverflow for natural sorting

```
SELECT * FROM category WHERE cat_name LIKE 'Level%' ORDER BY LEFT(cat_name,LOCATE(' ',cat_name)), CAST(SUBSTRING(cat_name,LOCATE(' ',cat_name)+1) AS SIGNED), cat_name ASC
```

but I don't know how I can integrate it with my first query. The closest I could get is

```
SELECT * FROM category ORDER BY LEFT(cat_name,LOCATE(' ',cat_name)), CAST(SUBSTRING(cat_name,LOCATE(' ',cat_name)+1) AS SIGNED),
(CASE WHEN cat_name LIKE 'Level%' THEN 0
ELSE 1
END) ASC, cat_name ASC
```

But the strings with Levels is off. It is arranged numerically but they are not occupying the top position.

- Apple
- Mango
- Others
- Level 1 Items
- Level 2 Items
- Level 3 Items
- Level 5 Items
- Level 10 Items
- Level 12 Items
- Level 22 Items
- Special Items

I think I am just missing something here. Hope someone can help me. Thanks in advance!

sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5a3eb/2

Comment: ...Personally, I'd define an 'ordering' table.  Among other things, doing dynamic ordering like this can cause indices to be ignored (because it has to read all entries, assign the rank, then sort, as opposed to being able to do index scans from a set of entries).  Depending on why you need to order entries this way, it also makes future revisions trivial (and non programmer-dependent).

Comment: Hi! I understand your point. I will consider it in the future. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with:

```
SELECT * FROM category 
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN cat_name LIKE 'Level%' THEN 0
ELSE 1
END)ASC,
LEFT(cat_name,LOCATE(' ',cat_name)), CAST(SUBSTRING(cat_name,LOCATE(' ',cat_name)+1) AS SIGNED),
  cat_name ASC
```

It's to do with the order of statements within your `ORDER BY`

Comment: You actually done all the work here, it was just the ordering of `ORDER BY`

Answer (score 1):

You also can use something like this -

```
SELECT * FROM category
ORDER BY
  IF(cat_name REGEXP '^(Level )[0-9]+( Items)$', 0, 1),
  TRIM(LEADING 'Level ' FROM cat_name)*1,
  cat_name
```

Comment: I think it should be TRIM( TRAILING ' Items' FROM TRIM(LEADING 'Level ' FROM cat_name)) * 1 instead...

Comment: It is enough to use first part.

Comment: Sorry, your solution is great, but I tried it against the sqlfiddle mentioned in the question, ordering is not correct.

Comment: Everething is OK, it was case-sensitive problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT * 
FROM category 
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN cat_name LIKE 'Level%' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) ASC, 
    LEFT(cat_name,LOCATE(' ',cat_name)), 
    CAST(SUBSTRING(cat_name,LOCATE(' ',cat_name)+1) AS SIGNED), cat_name ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add your first order by expression to the second query :)
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5a3eb/24

```
SELECT * FROM category 
ORDER BY 
(CASE WHEN cat_name LIKE 'Level%' THEN 0
ELSE 1
END),
LEFT(cat_name,LOCATE(' ',cat_name)), 
CAST(SUBSTRING(cat_name,LOCATE(' ',cat_name)+1) AS SIGNED)
, cat_name ASC
```

Comment: and why you order twice by: `(CASE WHEN cat_name LIKE 'Level%' THEN 0
ELSE 1
END)` ?